# Angular5 Server Side Rendering(Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error)

Tags: angular, angular5, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

Angular5 Server Side Rendering(Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error).

I believe the above error is something with CORS. But angular5 without the SSR the CORS is working fine.

This happens specifically when i change the Api to subdomain

> Laravel API  : http://api.localhost:80
>
> Node Express :http://localhost:3000

Below is the header which i have added for Laravel PHP api.

```
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type,Accept, X-Auth-Token ,App-Auth,X-XSRF-TOKEN,Authorization');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');
```

When communicating with Node to Laravel PHP , am getting the below error

```
Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]
    at resolvePromise (D:\ng\app-root\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:824:31)
    at resolvePromise (D:\ng\app-root\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:795:17)
    at D:\ng\app-root\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:873:17
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (D:\ng\app-root\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:425:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (D:\ng\app-root\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:4783:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (D:\ng\app-root\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:424:36)
    at Zone.runTask (D:\ng\app-root\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:192:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (D:\ng\app-root\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:602:35)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask (D:\ng\app-root\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:503:21)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (D:\ng\app-root\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:488:48)
  rejection: 
   HttpErrorResponse {
     headers: HttpHeaders { normalizedNames: Map {}, lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map {} },
     status: 0,
     statusText: 'Unknown Error',
     url: null,
     ok: false,
     name: 'HttpErrorResponse',
     message: 'Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error',
     error: 
      ProgressEvent {
        type: 'error',
        target: [Object],
        currentTarget: [Object],
        lengthComputable: false,
        loaded: 0,
        total: 0 } },
  promise: 
   ZoneAwarePromise {
     __zone_symbol__state: 0,
     __zone_symbol__value: 
      HttpErrorResponse {
        headers: [Object],
        status: 0,
        statusText: 'Unknown Error',
        url: null,
        ok: false,
        name: 'HttpErrorResponse',
        message: 'Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error',
        error: [Object] } },
  zone: 
   Zone {
     _properties: { isAngularZone: true },
     _parent: 
      Zone {
        _properties: {},
        _parent: null,
        _name: '',
        _zoneDelegate: [Object] },
     _name: 'angular',
     _zoneDelegate: 
      ZoneDelegate {
        _taskCounts: [Object],
        zone: [Circular],
        _parentDelegate: [Object],
        _forkZS: null,
        _forkDlgt: null,
        _forkCurrZone: [Object],
        _interceptZS: null,
        _interceptDlgt: null,
        _interceptCurrZone: [Object],
        _invokeZS: [Object],
        _invokeDlgt: [Object],
        _invokeCurrZone: [Circular],
        _handleErrorZS: [Object],
        _handleErrorDlgt: [Object],
        _handleErrorCurrZone: [Circular],
        _scheduleTaskZS: [Object],
        _scheduleTaskDlgt: [Object],
        _scheduleTaskCurrZone: [Circular],
        _invokeTaskZS: [Object],
        _invokeTaskDlgt: [Object],
        _invokeTaskCurrZone: [Circular],
        _cancelTaskZS: [Object],
        _cancelTaskDlgt: [Object],
        _cancelTaskCurrZone: [Circular],
        _hasTaskZS: [Object],
        _hasTaskDlgt: [Object],
        _hasTaskDlgtOwner: [Circular],
        _hasTaskCurrZone: [Circular] } },
  task: 
   ZoneTask {
     _zone: 
      Zone {
        _properties: [Object],
        _parent: [Object],
        _name: 'angular',
        _zoneDelegate: [Object] },
     runCount: 0,
     _zoneDelegates: null,
     _state: 'notScheduled',
     type: 'microTask',
     source: 'Promise.then',
     data: undefined,
     scheduleFn: undefined,
     cancelFn: null,
     callback: [Function],
     invoke: [Function] } }
```

Comment: I don't think it has something to do with CORS. Its not problem because both apps are running in same server

Comment: This happens only when I change the API to subdomain. I am experiencing the issue in my local development

Answer (score 2):

create a proxy.conf.json file to act as a proxy server.

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "your full api server url",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

And then modify the npm start command in package.json as below

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"
```

You can read more about this on following url

[Proxy To Backend](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md)

Comment: How about for angular universal.  This is already working without SSR.I have a problem with Server side rendering.

Comment: what do you mean by SSR?

Comment: server side rendering using Angular universal. I am having trouble only if change the api route to subdomain. This is working already for a server url http://localhost:80/api   but it throw error if i change the server route domain to http://api.localhost:80/api

Comment: Installed this plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog in google chrome and disable CORS

Comment: Thank you. This works for now. But how about production

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162024/discussion-between-santosh-singh-and-satz).

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a new virtual host with different name for Laravel API 
lets say http://api.apiserver.lo

This solves the issue , without installing the chrome plugin.